# Keycloak - external IDPs in Pop Up

Tags: openid-connect, keycloak

I am using keycloak in an iframe.
Behind my keycloak are some secondary IDPs like google and facebook.

With my current configuration, keycloak simply redirects to those secondary IDPs. This means they are beeing opened within the iframe aswell.
I'd really like to change that, since it contradicts some major security policies I have.

Can I somehow tell keycloak to open external IDPs in a pop up?
I have read the keycloak "server administration guide" but couldn't find any infos reagrding this issue.

Comment: How did you use this inside popup? Do you have any demo site or code how you implemented this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured out a workaround that involves a lot of js hacks.

1.

I changed the login.ftl of my login theme to not simply href for social providers, but to execute some js.
So before it was this:

```
<a href="${p.loginUrl}" id="zocial-${p.alias}" class="zocial ${p.providerId}">
```

Now it is this:

```
<a onclick="openInPopUp('${p.loginUrl}', '${name}')" id="zocial-${p.alias}" class="zocial ${p.providerId}">
<form id="kc_social_continue" method="post">
</form>
<script>
  function openInPopUp(url, name) {
    let popup = window.open(url, name, 'toolbar=no,width=600,height=600');
    let receiveMessage = (event) => {
      if (event.origin !== (window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname)){
        return;
      }
      document.forms['kc_social_continue'].action = event.data;
      document.forms['kc_social_continue'].submit();
    };
    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
  }
</script>
```

What this does is it opens the identity provider in a popup.

Furthermore a message listener is registered that expects an URL as message body. Whenever a message is received an empty form is posted to the respective URL.

2.

Add a custom Authentication SPI. This does nothing but presenting a custom freemarker template to the user.

```
public class ClosePopupAuthenticator implements Authenticator {
    @Override
    public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        Response challenge = context.form().createForm("close-popup.ftl");
        context.challenge(challenge);
    }
    @Override
    public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
        context.success();
    }
}
```

This close-popup.ftl sends its loginAction-URL to the parent window and then closes itself.

```
<script>
  let host = window.location.hostname;
  let protocol = window.location.protocol;
  window.opener.postMessage("${url.loginAction}", protocol + '//' + host);
  window.close();
</script>
```

3.

Add this new SPI to a new Flow and set this Flow as "Post Login Flow" for all relevant Identity Providers.